# Disable only .(DOT) special charecter in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-input

I don't want allow user to enter. (Dot) in my input field.. Rest of the required validation done already.

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ContactNumber" maxlength="10" value="" id="ContactNumber" title="Enter Number Here" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required>
```

Comment: i got the answer its just i need to remove keyEntry ==46

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
$("#name").on("keypress", function(evt) {
  var keycode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
  if (keycode == 46) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
```

Working example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikgaloria/8nz11auz/)

Comment: Ok, it seems like your conditional statements are incorrect in your code, I've tried with your validations here. See this Jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/pratikgaloria/hgnusen0/)

Comment: are we giving up testing for mobile now what is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("someRule", function(string, element) { 
    return !string.match(/\./g);
}, "Your username contains a dot!");
```

In HTML use the [pattern](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) attribute:

```
pattern="[^.]"
```

Comment: I don't see any hints that the TO is already using a validation plugin. And the `pattern` attribute isn't supported by all browsers -> http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern

Comment: I was going to write a vanilla JS solution too. But It has already been given

Comment: write` (keyEntry != '46')` instead of` (keyEntry == '46')` in your code