# Disable input dot '.' javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to disable user for input dot `.`. Here is what I try so far

```
$('#num').on('input', function (event) { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$//./, '');
});
```

with my script above, I still can input dot `.`. Is there anyway to prevent user to input dot `.` ?

thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you getting syntax error in `$//./`? You can just replace dots `.replace(/\.+/g, '');`

Comment: I disable dot using this : http://jsfiddle.net/pratikgaloria/8nz11auz/

Comment: This has already been answered in another post. I have linked it. [Answered Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072376/javascript-disable-only-dot-special-charecter-in-input-field)

Comment: [Remove dot from textbox on text input](//stackoverflow.com/q/5944046), [Prevent "DOT" for Input type number in Mobile Devices](//stackoverflow.com/q/17105058)

Comment: this part `/./` is only for try. Everything working fine if i remove that (Execpt disable dot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `keyCode` on the `keydown` event and do a `preventDefault` if it's 190 (the period key). Test below with "Run code snippet".

```js
$('#num').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 190 || e.keyCode === 110) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="num">
```

Comment: what is `190` ?

Comment: It's the numerical keyCode value for the period key. Read more about keyCodes here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: Better late then never, but this does not work if you use the period key on your numpad.

Comment: @Metalmini Looks like that might be "decimal point" on the keycodes list. Instead you could write `if (e.keyCode === 190 || e.keyCode == 110)`

Comment: Can you please also give this in javascript? it world be very helpful.